# How do i export a list of dataframes to each csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, export-to-csv

I have a list of dataframes and i want to export each element in different csv file. How can i do it? I'm newbie in python. Thanks in advance

```
col1 col2
a    b
c    d
```

df1 above

```
col3 col4
e    f
g    h
```

df2 above

```
list = [df1, df2]
```

Comment: Read about `for` loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by iterating over the list of dataframes and their names at the same time. The following code should work

```
dfs = [df1, df2]
names = ['df1', 'df2']

for df,name in zip(dfs, names): 
   df.to_csv(name + '.csv')
```